# lxml: Modifying a tree inplace

Tags: python, lxml

I have this simple function which adds new elements if they are missing:

```
def add_missing(root):
    """ Add missing elements and return `root` """
    for tag, missing_el in missing_tags.items():
        for elem in root.iterfind(".//" + tag):
            if elem.find(missing_el.tag) is None:
                elem.append(missing_el)
                print tostring(elem)
    print tostring(root)
    return root
```

however when I check root if it contains the missing elements I find only the last element to contain the newly appended element.

Can someone point out a way to modify an etree while iterating on it?

Answer (score 4):

Adding the same element in different places of the tree just moves that element around. Use of deepcopy fixed the issue:

```
from copy import deepcopy
def add_missing(root):
    """ Add missing elements and return `root` """
    for tag, missing_el in missing_tags.items():
        for elem in root.findall(".//" + tag):
            if elem.find(missing_el.tag) is None:
                elem.append(deepcopy(missing_el))
                print tostring(elem)
    print tostring(root)
    return root
```